# Songs banned from music stores

Tags: teaching

We all (should!) know that if you play "Smoke on the Water" or "Stairway to Heaven" in a guitar store, you run the risk of getting briskly tossed out on your keester.  The question a friend asked, are there equivalents for other instruments?  I suggested "Take 5" for saxophone, or perhaps "Yakkity Sax".  What songs should I avoid?

Edit: Qualified the "all"

Comment: Not sure this is on topic as it promotes discussion and list-type answers... Also, I'm not terribly certain that this is an actual thing other than what one might see in a movie, like Wayne's World. Music stores, like other businesses, want your money and won't risk a sale on the potential offense taken by one of its employees' ears

Comment: My piano favourite is a well known Scott Joplin piece, which I play in C r.h. and C# l.h. Gets some strange looks... Entertaining.

Comment: Really, this comes out as a "list question" to which there can be no single right answer & is therefore not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Tetsujin Maybe in that case it should be a community wiki question

Comment: I've never heard anything like this - what is the background? Do music shop keepers hear these songs just to often, or is it rather about good songs being ruined by low-level players?

Answer (score 1):

"lesson one" for piano and "für Elise"

I would throw the all out! ;)

Comment: I would say, there is something terribly wrong with this Für Elise Interpretation.

Comment: yes and then of course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2IK1zzm9Fw

Answer (score 1):

I've seen customers get asked to leave for playing chopsticks and heart and soul on the keyboards but those customers probably had no intention of making a purchase at that point in time. Music stores are often mistaken for music playgrounds and it can interfere with sales.